# Имеются две функции события клика в API Яндекс карты, как мне их вызывать при необходимости циклично?

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

```
//Мне нужно вызывать их по  очереди циклично, иначе происходит наложение одной на другую. 
myGeoObjects[0].events.add('click', function(e){
   $("#hidden_1").toggle(100);
   myMap.setCenter([55.740776, 52.406384],12);
});
myGeoObjects[1].events.add('click', function(e){
   $("#hidden_2").toggle(100);
   myMap.setCenter([54.905177, 52.298249],12);
});
```

Comment: Используйте цикл for с заданными параметрами http://javascript.ru/for

Answer (score 1):

```
function toggleDiv(id) {

for(i in showedDivs) { 
  if(id != showedDivs[i]) { 
     $("#"+showedDivs[i]).hide(); 
     delete(showedDivs[i]); }
}

if(!$('#'+id).is(':visible') ) {
    $('#'+id).show();
    showedDivs.push(id);
} else {
         $('#'+id).hide();
       }


}

myGeoObjects[0].events.add('click', function(e){
   //$("#hidden_1").toggle(100);
   toggleDiv('hidden_1');
   myMap.panTo([55.740776, 52.406384],{flying:false},{safe:false});

});

myGeoObjects[1].events.add('click', function(e){       
   //$("#hidden_2").toggle(100);
   toggleDiv('hidden_2');
   myMap.panTo([54.905177, 52.298249],{flying:false},{safe:false}); 


});
//это просто я добавил третью метку, но суть та же и она решена 
myGeoObjects[2].events.add('click', function(e){       
   //$("#hidden_3").toggle(100);
   toggleDiv('hidden_3');
   myMap.panTo([54.536413, 52.789489],{flying:false},{safe:false});

});
```

Comment: var showedDivs = []; лучше вынести на уровень выше за пределы функции function init () {.....} после ymaps.ready(init); var showedDivs = [];

Comment: Для совсем новичков myGeoObjects[2].events.add('click', function(e){       
   //$("#hidden_3").toggle(100);
   toggleDiv('hidden_3');
   myMap.panTo([54.536413, 52.789489],{flying:false},{safe:false}); это просто я добавил еще один геообъект (еще одну метку)